Aligning Key Sizes Between OpenSSL and liboqs-go for Signature Verification in Go
I am developing a cryptographic application in Go, aiming to utilize keys generated by both OpenSSL and liboqs-go for signing and verifying purposes. I'm using the Dilithium2 algorithm through both libraries, but I'm encountering an issue where the sizes of the generated keys are different, which might affect their interchangeability for signing and verifying processes. Here's how I am currently generating and serializing the keys using both libraries:
OpenSSL Key Generation and Serialization:
cmd := exec.Command("openssl", "genpkey", "-algorithm", "Dilithium2", "-out", "dilithium_private.pem")
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to generate key using OpenSSL: %v", err)
}

// Assuming the PEM file is correctly formed, let's decode it to check size
privateKeyData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("dilithium_private.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to read PEM file: %v", err)
}
block, _ := pem.Decode(privateKeyData)
if block == nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to decode PEM block")
}
log.Printf("Size of OpenSSL raw key data: %d bytes", len(block.Bytes))

liboqs-go Key Generation and Serialization:
signer := oqs.Signature{}
err := signer.Init("Dilithium2", nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to initialize signer: %v", err)
}
defer signer.Clean()

publicKey, secretKey, err := signer.GenerateKeyPair()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to generate key pair: %v", err)
}

// Serialize keys to PEM format
writeKeyToFile("liboqs_private.pem", secretKey, "PRIVATE KEY")
writeKeyToFile("liboqs_public.pem", publicKey, "PUBLIC KEY")

// Let's assume writeKeyToFile logs the size of the key

Observed Output:

Size of OpenSSL raw key data: 3870 bytes
Size of liboqs-go raw key data: 2528 bytes

Goal:
I need the keys to be of similar sizes to ensure they can be used interchangeably for signing and verifying functions in a system that might use either of the libraries to generate or validate signatures.
Question:
How can I align the sizes of the keys generated by OpenSSL and liboqs-go? Are there specific configurations in either library that can standardize key sizes, or is there another approach to ensure the keys are functionally equivalent for my purposes?
Additional Details:
Both keys are generated using the same algorithm (Dilithium2). The discrepancy in size raises concerns about their compatibility in cryptographic operations, especially for functions that expect a certain key format or size.


EDIT 07/08/2024 - RESOLVED

I have the same problem as you regarding the size of the post quantum private key generated by OpenSSL and by a Go library (other than liboqs-go): https://github.com/cloudflare/circl
OpenSSL generates a key pair containing both private key and public key and stores it into one file, encoded in ASN.1 format. What needs to be done is to extract the private key contained in this file.
To give you an idea, this is what has been done in the Go crypto/x509 library, in the ParsePKCS8PrivateKey function (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/x509/pkcs8.go#L35). So, the cases for Dilithium2/3/5 keys should be handled here to retrieve the private key as below :
// pkcs8 reflects an ASN.1, PKCS #8 PrivateKey. See
// ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-8/pkcs-8v1_2.asn
// and RFC 5208.
type pkcs8 struct {
    Version int
    Algo    pkix.AlgorithmIdentifier
    PrivateKey []byte
    // optional attributes omitted.
}

func ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(der []byte) (key any, err error) {
    var p8 pkcs8
    if _, err := asn1.Unmarshal(der, &p8); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Extract the private key and public key bytes from PKCS8 data
    keyPairBytes := p8.PrivateKey

    var p8Decoded []byte
    // Unmarshal the ASN.1 encoded data into the OctetString structure
    if _, err = asn1.Unmarshal(keyPairBytes, &p8Decoded); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    switch {
    case privKey.Algo.Algorithm.Equal(oidPublicKeyDilithium2):
        // Exctract only the private key
        var privateKeyBytes [dilithium2.PrivateKeySize]byte
        copy(privateKeyBytes[:], p8Decoded)

        // Unpack data into Dilithium2 Private Key
        var key dilithium2.PrivateKey
        key.Unpack(&privateKeyBytes)
        return &key, nil
    case privKey.Algo.Algorithm.Equal(oidPublicKeyDilithium3):
        // Same logic as above
    case privKey.Algo.Algorithm.Equal(oidPublicKeyDilithium5):
        // Same logic as above
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("x509: PKCS#8 wrapping contained private key with unknown algorithm: %v", privKey.Algo.Algorithm)
    }

}

Note that I am using the cloudlfare/circl library so please, adjust dilithium2.PrivateKey with the equivalent for liboqs-go.
You are now able to use private key generated by OpenSSL in your Go application.
This function can parse private key generated by OpenSSL, but if you want to generate key pair with Go and then use it with OpenSSL, you need to append the private key bytes with public key bytes, and then encode keypair bytes into ASN.1 format.
